# Typescript: intellisense does not recognize the right type returned by a method using http.post

Tags: angular, typescript, intellisense, angular-http

I have the following piece of code

```
  getLoggingCsvRecords(recId: string) {
    const url = this.apiurl + 'loggingcsvrecordsforrecid';
    return this.http.post<Array<string>>(url, {recId})
                      .map(data => data['results']);
  }
```

I would expect intellisense to recognize that the type returned by the `getLoggingCsvRecords()` method is `Obsevable<Array<string>>`.
On the contrary intellisense suggests `Observable<any>` as the  right type.
Where am I wrong?

I am using VSCode as IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return signature in the wrong place.

```
GetLoggingRecords(recId: string): Observable<Array<string>> {
  Your code

  return this.http.post(rest of stuff)
}
```

Comment: I read somewhere the possibility to write `http.post<MyType>()` but probably I did not understand the real meaning

Comment: That’s probably for casting which you want to avoid

Answer (score -1):

Based on what you have written the HTTP Post returns an array of strings. However, you appear to map this like an object.

Perhaps you meant something like this?

```
interface ILoggingRecord {
    results: string;
}

// ...

getLoggingCsvRecords(recId: string) {
    const url = this.apiurl + 'loggingcsvrecordsforrecid';
    return this.http.post<Array<ILoggingRecord>>(url, {recId})
        .map(data => data['results']);
}
```

The call should be able to understand that the data is an array of objects. The result of the map, therefore is a string. If this doesn't work try `data => data.results` instead. String access to properties can confuse the syntax analyser.

Comment: Might be worth checking the official documentation as it is hard to say the exact return type. https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response But in summary "You can, however, tell HttpClient what type the response will be, which is recommended" as above.